# Trying to make the border curve inwards

Tags: html, css

So what I'm trying to do is to make the border of an `asp:Table` curve inwards (like `border-radius`, but inwards). A picture of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I can't put the content in a `div` and curve its corners, because that wouldn't allow me to go with the look I'm going for on my site.
what I'm trying to do on this page is have the `table`'s borders in the same background color as the background.
this is my code currently:

```css
html,body, #main_div{
           height: 100%;
        }
        body {
          background-color: #1862A1;
          background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #1862A1, #8529B1);
          padding-bottom: 0;
          padding-top: 0;
          margin: 0;
        }
        .main_table{
            height: 100%;
            width: 80%;
            background-color: transparent;
            min-height: 61vh;
        }
        .album{
            width: 8vw;
            height: 8vw;
        }
        .inside{
            background-color: white;
            width: 25vh;
            height: 27vh;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }
        .border{
            border: 3px solid white;
        }
        #continuation{
            min-height: 39vh;
            background-color: white;
            width: 80%;
        }
```

```html
<body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <center>
                <table id="Table1" runat="server" CellPadding="0" GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="Center" class="main_table">
                <tr class="border">
                    <td class="border">
                        <center>
                            <table class="inside">
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Image src="../pics/ADHD.jpeg" ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="album"></asp:Image></center></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="album_button"></asp:Button></center></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </center>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border">
                        <center>
                        <table class="inside">
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Image src="../pics/all-eyez-on-me.png" ID="Image2" runat="server" CssClass="album"></asp:Image></center></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="album_button"></asp:Button></center></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </center>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border">
                        <center>
                        <table class="inside">
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Image src="../pics/DAMN.jpg" ID="Image3" runat="server" CssClass="album"></asp:Image></center></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="album_button"></asp:Button></center></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </center>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border">
                        <center>
                        <table class="inside">
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Image src="../pics/detroit-2.jpg" ID="Image4" runat="server" CssClass="album"></asp:Image></center></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="album_button"></asp:Button></center></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </center>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border">
                        <center>
                        <table class="inside">
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Image src="../pics/ISSA.jpg" ID="Image5" runat="server" CssClass="album"></asp:Image></center></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="album_button"></asp:Button></center></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="border">
                    <td class="border">
                        <center>
                        <table class="inside">
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Image src="../pics/forst-hills-drive.jpg" ID="Image6" runat="server" CssClass="album"></asp:Image></center></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="album_button"></asp:Button></center></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </center>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border">
                        <center>
                        <table class="inside">
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Image src="../pics/hollywoods-bleading.jpg" ID="Image7" runat="server" CssClass="album"></asp:Image></center></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="album_button"></asp:Button></center></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </center>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border">
                        <center>
                        <table class="inside">
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Image src="../pics/kirk.jpg" ID="Image8" runat="server" CssClass="album"></asp:Image></center></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="album_button"></asp:Button></center></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </center>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border">
                        <center>
                        <table class="inside">
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Image src="../pics/TA13OO.jpg" ID="Image9" runat="server" CssClass="album"></asp:Image></center></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="album_button"></asp:Button></center></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </center>
                    </td>
                    <td class="border">
                        <center>
                        <table class="inside">
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Image src="../pics/without-warning.jpg" ID="Image10" runat="server" CssClass="album"></asp:Image></center></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td><center><asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="album_button"></asp:Button></center></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            </center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                <div id="continuation">
                </div>
        </center>
        </form>
    </body>
```

In the snippet, I switched the `asp:Table` tag with `table`, the `asp:TableRow` tag with `tr`, and the `asp:TableCell` tag with `td`.

Currently, the code is producing this:
[image]

To create the illusion that the border around the `table`s is like a cutout in the div, I'll have to make the border in the `.border` class be like in the picture, or use another method - anyone has any ideas?

Comment: There are no inverted borders. You either do that with the use of pseud elements that are dispalyed over the border and cuts them away or with the use of a normal border of an inner element. Also you have no tabular data. As such the use of a table is a wrong use. USe CSS-Grid for your design or flexbox if you need to fully support IE.

Comment: in each cell, there's a photo and a button as seen in the image below the snippet, the table does contain data

Comment: A photo and a button are both not tabular data. Tabular data are something like a list of names, birthdays...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simulate this using `radial-gradient()`

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:5px solid #fff;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top left    ,transparent 97%,#fff) bottom right,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right   ,transparent 97%,#fff) bottom left,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left ,transparent 97%,#fff) top right,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,transparent 97%,#fff) top left;
  background-size:30px 30px; /* adjust this */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red,blue)
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Another idea using border-image:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #fff;
  border-image: radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent 97%, #fff) 100;
  border-image-width: 40px; /* adjust this */
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue)
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I'll try working with that and changing my code, thanks!